# Create a 3D array made of repetitions of a matrix in a specific way

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array

I would like to repeat a matrix in a way that I don't manage to do with the function repmat. Namely, I want a matrix B that is such that a column-wise cross-section of it would give me matrix A. When I use `repmat(A,[1,1,col_nb])`, you would have to take a cross-section of the third dimension to get matrix A.

Let me put an example below:

```
A = [1,2,3;4,5,6];
not_B = repmat(A,[1,1,3]); % What I am getting at the moment

% not_B(:,:,1) = A
% not_B(:,:,2) = A
% not_B(:,:,3) = A

% What I would like
B(:,1,:) = A;
B(:,2,:) = A;
B(:,3,:) = A;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`repelem`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html) to avoid extra `permute` operation:

```
[r c] = size(A);
rep = 3;
B = reshape(repelem(A,1,rep),r,rep,c)
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe all you need is a call to [`permute`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html):

```
B = permute(repmat(A, [1 1 3]), [1 3 2]);
```

However, it should be noted that the matrices you get from `B(:, i, :)` will not be 3-by-3 anymore. They will be 3-by-1-by-3. You may want to use [`squeeze`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/squeeze.html) like so:

```
C = squeeze(B(:, 1, :));  % C will match A
```